# How to access xampp installed application windows server

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2008

I have installed ISS and Xampp in windows 2008 r2, port of Apache was configured to 8080. Installed a application in c:\xampp\htdoc\hrms.

IP of the machine is `192.168.1.11`; from the server I was able to access the application(orangeHR) directly by following syntax and that works fine.

`http://192.168.1.11:8080/hrms` also `http://localhost:8080/hrms`

When I was trying to connect using laptop(connected to network via WiFi) using `http://192.168.1.11:8080/hrms` there is no response - blank white page appears.

Alternatively - when I type only the IP `http://192.168.1.11` - IIS7 - Default page displays in my Laptop so I tried `http://192.168.1.11:8080/` - no response - please advice.

Comment: Are u able to ping from laptop?

Comment: Change firewall settings for port `8080` on `192.168.1.11`

Comment: How to change firewall  setting - kindly advice

Comment: Which Windows OS are you using?

Comment: Windows-server- 2008 r2